# Mini-Profiler with Simple.Data

Tags: .net, mvc-mini-profiler, simple.data

Is it possible to use Mini-Profiler with Simple.Data Library? I use it to get data from MySql like this:

```
var db = Database.OpenConnection(ConnectionString);
var book = db.Books.FindById(id);
```

How can I user Profiler with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell Simple.Data to use a pre-existing connections and wrap your connection with a profiled connection:

```
var db = Database.OpenConnection(ConnectionString);
using (var rawCnn =  new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 
using (var profiledCnn = new MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(rawCnn, MiniProfiler.Current);
{
    profiledCnn.Open();
    ((AdoAdapter)db.GetAdapter()).UseSharedConnection(profiledCnn);
    book = db.Books.FindById(id);
    ((AdoAdapter)db.GetAdapter()).StopUsingSharedConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new hook that was [added](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/commit/24b35f7662854d517071e90d20187591c2eb57ac) to `Simple.Data` which allows for better integration with MiniProfiler.

`AdoAdapter.ConnectionCreated += (o, args) => args.OverrideConnection(new ProfiledDbConnection((DbConnection)args.Connection, MiniProfiler.Current));`

This basicallt allows you to hookup to the connection created event and override it with your own profiled connection.

*NOTE: As of writing of this post, this change isn't in the nuget package yet. so you need your custom build of `Simple.Data`*